# How to get wishlist for the user who logged in

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.6, query-builder

I want to do something like, a user logged in, so only those wishlists he has done for him, he can see that. What I'm getting is all wishlist for every user.

> controller

```
$user_id = Session::get('id')
$products = DB::table('wishlist')
        ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'wishlist.user_id')
        ->join('product', 'product.id', '=', 'wishlist.product_id')
        ->select('product.*')
        ->get();

return view('Users.userlayout')
        ->with(compact('products'));
```

I've created **Wishlist, Users, Product** Model. Failed to work with Eloquent too. Wishing to get both solve.

Wishlist table column: **id, product_id, user_id**
I guess I have to use that **$user_id** in the query table but failed to do that.

> NB: I've solved this problem with query builder, would like to get help
>   for Eloquent relationship

Comment: please add your migrations

Comment: Can you please be more specific? Cause I need to solve this query to get those products are in the wishlist for the user logged in.

Comment: dont you created migration files for db tables

Comment: Actually, I'm ignoring the migrations system, cause if I have to change anything in a table, I have to refresh the database, it's really painful or a bit tough. I'm handling the tables directly from localhost. BTW I've solved this problem with `query builder`

Comment: Provide your migrations.

Comment: It seems that your relationship or db design is a little bit wrong.

Comment: Can you please mention, what's wrong so that I can correct myself. @HCK

Comment: Your question is not very well structured. You're not asking something, you're asking for people to code something for you. For you to do this with an eloquent relation you need to build it first on your model, I suggest you research the eloquent docs for relationships and when you get stuck you ask again - but at the very least attempt to do it yourself. Youre going to need to get the user object first User::find($id) and then call a relationship on it ->products()

Comment: I've tried in many ways, after that I solved it with query builder. As just a beginner, I gotta need some help, I try to get things to know briefly so that I can understand, not just the solution. Thanks for your advice. @marina Mosti

Comment: @Eyakub I recommend you to read the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs) (is very well written) or watch the ["Laravel From Scratch"](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-from-scratch-2018) series on Laracasts.